# Get values from appsettings.json in .net core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net-core

What I'm trying to do *should* be simple but I can not get it to work!!

My `appsettings.json` file:

```
{
  "AppSettings": {
    "myKey": "myValue",
  }
}
```

And then:

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
var myValue = config["myKey"];
```

`myValue` is null.

I also tried:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();
IConfiguration config = builder.Build();

var myValue = config.GetSection("myKey");
```

But again, `myValue` is null.

Comment: you don't have an startup.cs ?

Comment: @Mehrdad, this is inside a unit test project

Comment: Shouldn't that be `"myKey"` (the name of your key)?

Comment: In your code sample do you mean config["myKey"] or are you doing config["myValue"]?

Comment: @knittl Typo! Trust me, it's correct in the actual code. See edited OP.

Comment: @Steve Typo! Trust me, it's correct in the actual code. See edited OP.

Comment: You probably need to dereference into the inner `"AppSettings"` dictionary. What happens if you debug, add a breakpoint after getting the section and then inspecting the variable? I assume it has `"AppSettings"` as key, not `"myKey"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your appsettings.json `myKey` is inside an AppSettings object.

That whole object is being loaded, so you'll need to reference it:

```cs
var myValue = config["AppSettings:myKey"];
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#hierarchical-configuration-data

Comment: Nailed it!  Thank you!! Wow... spent hours on this. Much appreciated. Followup question: of the two examples/attempts I have above, which is better, and why?

Comment: I wouldn't use `SetBasePath` and `AddEnvironmentVariables` unless they're really necessary, keeping it simple.

Comment: using `optional: false` sounds like a good idea, you wouldn't want your tests to run without the proper config values, since they'll probably fail anyway.

Comment: could I also draw your attention to this quesion? :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60441040/deserialize-appsettings-json-in-unit-test

Comment: Suppose in the dev json file I created key called `key1` and in prod json file I create key called `key2`, then when I run the project in visual studio, it is reading both the keys. Shouldn't it read only the key from the dev json file?

Answer (score 0):

You have to write `var myValue = config["AppSettings:myKey"];` instead of `var myValue = config.GetSection("myKey");`, Because `myKey` is inside of `AppSettings:myKey`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).