# Deserialize appsettings.json in unit test

Tags: c#, .net-core

There are *many* examples out there that show how to deserialize your app settings within the `Startup.cs` class. I get that. But that's not what I'm asking.  I'm working within a unit test constructor.

This question is close: [Read appsettings json values in .NET Core Test Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39791634/read-appsettings-json-values-in-net-core-test-project)
But in reading it carefully, I'm not seeing a slam dunk answer.

appsettings.json:

```
{
  "AppSettings": {
    "myKey1": "myValue1",
    "myKey2": "myValue2",
  }
}
```

And:

```
public class AppSettings
{
    public string myKey1 { get; set; }
    public string myKey2 { get; set; }
}
```

I am able to get single values just fine:

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
              .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
              .Build();
var myValue1 = config.GetSection("AppSettings:myKey1 ").Value;
```

But what I'm not figuring out is how to get create an instance of `AppSettings`. I've tried:

```
var appSettings = config.GetValue<AppSettings>("AppSettings");
```

But that ends up null. And I've played around with trying to create my own instance of `IServiceCollection` so I could do something like you might in `Startup.cs`, but I'm not making any progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just doing this.

```
public class AppSettings
{
    AppSettings(IConfigurationRoot config)
    {
            myKey1 = config.GetSection("AppSettings:MyKey1").Value;
            myKey2 = config.GetSection("AppSettings:MyKey2").Value;
    }

    public string myKey1 { get; set; }
    public string myKey2 { get; set; }
}
```

Not ideal but it gets the job done and I can move on.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder` extension, available as a separate package on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder/).

Specifically, use the  [Configuration.Bind()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbinder.bind?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) method:

```
AppSettings appSettings;

config.Bind(appSettings);
```

Or even simpler:

```
var appSettings = config.Get<AppSettings>();
```

You could also bind it with help of DI:

```
services.Configure<AppSettings>(_configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
```

Then in your service that needs these settings, just add `AppSettings appSettings` as a dependency to it and the dependency should auto-resolve.

Comment: I think this is the same thing nollidge is suggesting? If so, it does indeed create an instance of `AppSettings` but all of the properties are null.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston Okay, I usually do this with DI. Could you try out the suggestion in my edit?

Comment: So as I said in the OP, this is not iniside of a standard project This is a unit test. So there is no `startup.cs` where I can inject using `services`.

Comment: You could _definitely_ use dependency injection in a unit test. Have you tried out fixtures? They're really powerful and allow you to create your own DI container to be used by your unit tests.

Comment: fixtures? Not familiar.

Comment: Could you post some code of your unit test setup? What testing framework are you using?

Comment: The framework is just out of the box Visual Studio. Add > New Project > xUnit Test Project (.NET Core). As for setup, again, I'm just out of the box starting with an empty test class, going one step at a time.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston Read more about them here: https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context#class-fixture

Answer (score 1):

### Short answer

```
var section = config.GetSection(nameof(AppSettings));
var settings = section.Get<AppSettings>
```

### Long answer

You can't just do `config.Get<AppSettings>` as implied by other answers.  That tries to bind the whole config file to that class, which doesn't work, resulting in silent failure (null members).

*Microsoft documentation references for IConfiguration.Get method:*

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbinder.get
- https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder/ConfigurationBinder.cs,b4d3072eff1d97dc,references

You need to get the section first before deserializing to a settings object instance:

```
var section = config.GetSection(nameof(AppSettings));
var settings = section.Get<AppSettings>
```

You can use `Bind` instead of `Get` if desired:

```
var section = config.GetSection(nameof(AppSettings));
var settings = new AppSettings();
section.Bind(settings);
```

There are other overloads for if your section's name doesn't match your settings class's name.

### Bonus: extension methods

```
public static class IConfigurationExtensions
{
    public static T GetSection<T>(this IConfiguration config) where T : class, new()
    {
        IConfigurationSection section = config.GetSection(typeof(T).Name);
        return section.Get<T>();
    }
}

// Usage
var settings = config.GetSection<AppSettings>();
```

Going beyond the original question, you can inject these settings sections like this (using the extension method above):

```
public static class IServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddSingletonConfigSection<T>(
        this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config) where T : class, new()
    {
        T section = config.GetSection<T>();
        services.AddSingleton<T>(section);
        return services;
    }

    public static IServiceCollection AddScopedConfigSection<T>(
        this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config) where T : class, new()
    {
        services.AddScoped<T>(_ => config.GetSection<T>());
        return services;
    }
}

// Usage
services.AddSingletonConfigSection<AppSettings>(config);
services.AddScopedConfigSection<AppSettings>(config);
```

Comment: Great answer, this helped me immediately

Comment: `There are other overloads for if your section's name doesn't match your settings class's name.`
What are these? I don't see anything in the ConfigurationBinder options for this specification.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would have to create a new instance of `IConfiguration` and then get its values like you already are doing.

```cs
public UnitTestConstructor(IConfiguration configuration){
      Configuration = configuration;
}

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

public TestOne(){
      var appSettingsValue = Configuration.GetValue<string>("AppSettings:MyValue");
}
```

Comment: Why would they need a new instance of IConfiguration when they already have one?

Comment: I'm not sure you understood my question. I know how to get `AppSettings:MyValue` as a string.  What I am tying to get is this: `Configuration.GetValue<AppSetting>("AppSettings");`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use [`ConfigurationBinder.Get<T>()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbinder.get?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) (instead of `ConfigurationBinder.GetValue<T>()`

Comment: This got me close! But all properties of `AppSettings` are null.

Comment: Are you sure your appsettings.json is being written to the output dir? IConfiguration will return null for whatever you pass it if the keys don't exist to begin with.

Comment: `CopyToOutputDirectory` is set to `copyIfNewer`. Is that what you are asking?